# Editing product categories suddenly crashes website and goes back to wordpress installation

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, fatal-error

This has happened multiple times in the past week, and I'm not sure what's causing it.

Basically, I have a ton of categories (though, i'm not sure if this plays a part in the problem) and when i'm editing the them, such as changing the parent or editing product display, the website will suddenly crash, and when I go back to visit the url of the site, the wordpress installation is there, and I don't know what to make of this. Sometimes it'd just fix itself after a few mins, but obviously, I don't want to encounter this again.

I only have a screenshot of the wordpress installation, but it just looks like any other wordpress installation, so I'm not sure if it would help.

Does anyone know what I can do to prevent this from happening again? Because obviously, this is a huge security issue for my website.

Comment: I also apologize if this sounds so vague. I really have no clue how to explain it other than what I encountered so far. Hopefully if someone encountered this same bug has an idea how to fix this. Thank you

Comment: Do you know how to turn on debugging and show the results? https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/

Comment: Wordpress usually returns to installation mode if wp-config.php is missing, or not configure

Answer (score 0):

If you really have a LOT of categories and your host is not very good you might be causing some sort of issue with the database. Check the WP error log as CK MacLeod said. If your web host has a log file you can access that could be helpful as well.